# Product options drop down?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm using Drupal Commerce on my site, and I'm trying to add a drop down menu that allows my users to select a product size (S, M, L), and I want the price calculated based on their selection. **E.g.** each quantity is a different price (*S = 25, M = 50...etc*). This seems like it should be simple, but it's not something that looks do-able with commerce core? What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: See, [Product Attributes & Variations](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations) 

Comment: Oddly enough @NoSssweat, I don't have the "Products Display" option when I go to my content admin?

Comment: You'll need to create one, like in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FoZczcpbeM&list=PLZaG0MNecryMb3vktSsAJHKICpXc1AlW4&index=3). If something doesn't make sense, then watch the first 2 videos, as this is video #3.

Comment: Got it - thanks @NoSssweat :) Created manually, all is well lol. This is seems like such a labour intensive way to have to do this (especially if you've got 100+ products, each with 4 different pricing options). :/

Comment: Try [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/167472/add-product-variations-to-product-display-with-rules#answer-167487) out.

Comment: Another option, might be to use [Commerce Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_feeds) and with excel simply create a .csv with all the product variations and then import.